# Удалить элемент ( ' ' ) из списка

Tags: python

Как я могу удалить кавычки `' '` из списка `с = [1,2,3,'a',2,1,2,b,2,'1',1,c]` чтобы получить `с = [1,2,3,a,2,1,2,b,2,1,1,c]`

Comment: Тут кавычки нельзя "удалить". В этой записи кавычки означают, что объект является строкой (в отличии от остальных, которые являются числами). Конвертировать все элементы в числа можно, например, так `c = [int(v) for v in c]`.

Comment: @RomanKonoval там так же есть С которая является переменной, возможно ему нужна функция eval

Comment: Похоже у вас отсутствует понимание что такое переменная и что такое объект. В Пайтоне объект в кавычках является экземпляром класса str. Если содержимое объекта не число, то приведение к int вызовет исключение(ошибку).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере я заметил преобразование `'a'` в `a`. Как я понял, вы хотите заменить строки, на переменные соответствующие им. Если я понял правильно, то вот пример такого кода:

```
c = [1, 2, 3, 'a', 2, 1, 2, b, 2, '1', 1, d]

c = list(map(lambda x: eval(str(x)), c))
```

Comment: лямбда функция составлена неудачно, не следует пихать в евал всё подряд, лямбда функция разрешает оператор иф. оптимальнее былобы как то так c = list(map(lambda x: eval(x) if isinstance(x,str) else x, c)), на случай если элемент списка есть пользовательский объект с перегружеными функциями

Answer (score 1):

Перебираем элементы списка, каждый преобразовываем к типу `int`:

```
def rot(array):
    return [int(item) for item in array]
rot([1,2,3,'1',2,1,2,1,2,'1',1,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Перебор списка и приведения типа в int

```
c = [1,2,3,'1',2,1,2,1,2,'1',1,1]

d = list(map(lambda x: int(x) , c))
```